# Share toy box with other local user profiles

Tags: xbox-360, disney-infinity-2.0, disney-infinity

I have an Xbox Live account connected to a Disney online account.  I have a Toy Box that I created locally and also uploaded to my Disney account.  My kids have local profiles on the Xbox 360 that are not Xbox Live accounts (and, therefore, not Disney online accounts, either).

Is there any way that they can load my saved toy box from their profiles or would I have to create Xbox Live and Disney online accounts for them?  I would rather not do that unless I have to.

Comment: Without having tried, my guess is that you need Live accounts that see each other as "friends" to do the download...